# SQL LIMIT, but from the end

Tags: sql, postgresql

Can you `LIMIT` a query from the end of the results, rather than from the beginning? In particular, I'm looking for a solution w/ Postgresql, if that makes a difference.

Allow me to clarify with an example.

Let's say I want to return the 3 oldest people in my `people` table, but in ascending order of age. The best way I know how to select the 3 people returns the correct records, but in the reverse order:

```
SELECT * FROM people
ORDER BY age DESC
LIMIT 2
```

Comment: @marc_s, yes, but then they are in the wrong order

Comment: See Kshitij's answer - sort in the opposite direction, take TOP 2, then sort back again

Answer (score 9, accepted):

should be this way-

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT *
FROM PEOPLE
ORDER BY AGE DESC
LIMIT 3 ) X
ORDER BY AGE ASC
```

Comment: I edited the query to add an alias after the subquery; I'm pretty sure that's required by PostgreSQL.