# SQL Selecting all BUT the last row in a table?

Tags: sql

How can I select all BUT the last row in a table?

I know I can select the last via `SELECT item FROM table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1` but I want to select ALL but the last.

How can I do this?

Selecting a certain amount and using `ASC` won't work because I won't know how many rows there are.

I thought about doing a row count and taking that amount and selecting that -1 and using `ORDER BY id ASC` but are there any easier ways?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If Id is unique, you can do it as follows:

```
SELECT ...
FROM MyTable
WHERE Id < (SELECT MAX(Id) FROM MyTable)
```

Comment: how can I do the same thing If I dont have a primary key column in my table??

Answer (score 10):

The easiest way to do this is to discard the row in the application. You can do it in SQL by using a calculated limit. Calculate it as `(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM T) - 1`.

Or:

```
SELECT *
FROM T
EXCEPT
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM T
ORDER BY id ASC
```

Excluding the last row.

Comment: I'm sure you can fix it. The idea works. The idea was the hard part. Syntax is easy to look up. I'm not a MySQL guy.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM T LIMIT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM T) - 1`

Answer (score 2):

If you are fine with having results sorted by `DESC`, then you could also use any of the answers from: [How to skip the first n rows in sql query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29894645/how-to-skip-the-first-n-rows-in-sql-query) to achieve this.

This approach can also be easily generalized to "select all but the last N rows".

Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be a single standardized syntax for it, each DBMS has its own.

E.g. in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70244586/895245) I cover PostgreSQL, SQLite and MysQL. In PostgreSQL for example you could just use `OFFSET` without `LIMIT`:

```
SELECT item FROM table ORDER BY id DESC OFFSET 1
```

There doesn't seem to be a super nice way to also keep the order though without subqueries: [SQL LIMIT, but from the end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11200808/sql-limit-but-from-the-end)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work

```
 select * 
 from table
 where id not in (SELECT id FROM table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1)
```

Comment: Performance wise, this is horrible. If you have `n` rows in your table, this results in `O(n^2)` operations as it traverses the generated list for every row

Comment: @RubenHelsloot -- sounds like someone didn't create an index.

Comment: @RubenHelsloot The subquery result set is an invariant and is only retrieved once per the whole query. The performance is `O(n)` even without indexes. Just run `EXPLAIN` and see for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Since LIMIT can't get parameters you have two options - Build a dynamic query (see this post for more details - [passing LIMIT as parameters to MySQL sproc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2875238/passing-limit-as-parameters-to-mysql-sproc)) or filter it in your application.