# Reverse results of PostgreSQL after using ORDER BY

Tags: php, postgresql-9.1, morris.js

I have a query where I need to select the latest 25 entries to my database, but inverse the order of the results of that select.

I've come up with:

```
SELECT indexID, datetime, temperature FROM dataB WHERE userID="4236" ORDER BY indexID DESC, datetime ASC LIMIT 25
```

But I'm still getting the results in chronological order starting from newest, but I want chronological oldest to newest WITHIN those 25 newest. I'm using PHP's **pg_fetch_row()** and creating a concatenated string with the results and feeding that into a Morris.js graph, where my data is being graphed backwards because of this query.

How do I reverse the results of a query?

Comment: Not 100% sure what you mean but if you want the most recent then you must: ORDER BY datetime DESC, indexID DESC LIMIT 25... OR... ORDER BY indexID DESC, datetime DESC LIMIT 25... if indexID is sequential.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11200808/sql-limit-but-from-the-end/11200826

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try this , first fetch data in descending  orders after that use as temporary table and again select in  ascending order

```
SELECT indexID, datetime, temperature FROM (SELECT indexID, datetime, temperature FROM dataB WHERE userID="4236" ORDER BY indexID DESC LIMIT 25) temp order by indexID ASC
```

Comment: I am sure it will work, I have edited it i did little bit mistake in query but now it is ok

Comment: I hadn't thought about doing it this way, it's logical and clean, but I just don't understand where the "temp" is coming from, as it's throwing an error.`ERROR:  column temp.indexid does not exist`

Comment: (SELECT indexID, datetime, temperature FROM dataB WHERE userID="4236" ORDER BY indexID DESC LIMIT 25) order by indexID   
Try this also I hope it will work

Comment: `ERROR:  subquery in FROM must have an alias`

Comment: I'll keep tinkering with it though, you pointed me in the right direction, Vinod

Comment: SELECT indexID, datetime, temperature FROM (SELECT indexID, datetime, temperature FROM dataB WHERE userID=&quot;4236&quot; ORDER BY indexID DESC LIMIT 25) as temp order by temp.indexID ASC

I am not sure but I think you should try this also

Comment: I ended up getting it with this:
`SELECT indexid, datetime, temperature FROM (SELECT indexid, datetime, temperature, FROM dataB WHERE userID='4236' ORDER BY indexID DESC LIMIT 25) temp order by indexid ASC` 

I'll mark your answer as correct since it was close enough and led to getting it working.

Comment: You know you're allowed to use newlines in SQL queries ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of putting the results directly into a string, load them up in an array. When the array is full, use the `array_reverse` function to reverse the order of the elements in the array. You can now build your string and pass the data to your Morris graph.

Documentation: http://php.net/manual/ro/function.array-reverse.php

Comment: Unfortunately, the way I'm feeding the data into Morris.js, it makes it a string. array_reverse gets real angry about that since it's not an array anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add an offset along with a limit to your query. Below example shows an offset which basically gets the total number of rows that match your query and subtracts 25 from it to offset you to start from the "25th last" record which matches your query:

```
SELECT indexID, datetime, temperature
FROM dataB WHERE userID="4236"
ORDER BY indexID DESC, datetime ASC
LIMIT (( SELECT COUNT(indexID) FROM dataB WHERE userID="4236" )-25), 25;
```

Comment: The database this is coming from will be growing to a very large size, wouldn't this take a longer and longer time to process?